# Facebook login without leaving the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Although I've seen a few questions about this, I could not find a specific answer.

I'm using login button `FBSDKLoginButton` to login with facebook in my `iOS`app and native `facebook app` always open with the screen for authorization. And it shows the message "You have already authorized this app", when I press ok, I go back to my app and login works fine.

Now, I've seen quite a few apps where this is not the behavior, it just logs in without leaving the app. How can I achieve this behavior?

I've tried `facebookLoginButton.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;`but had no luck.

**UPDATE**

---

This is de `button`setup:

```
// Facebook
    self.facebookLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends", @"user_hometown", @"user_location", @"user_birthday", @"user_actions.fitness"];
    self.facebookLoginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"publish_actions"];
    self.facebookLoginButton.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
    self.facebookLoginButton.delegate = self;
```

Comment: You should link the Q/A's that you have read edit them into your question and why the answers of them didn't work for you. Also what makes your case different than all the other similiar posts, to avoid getting this flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: try to check FBSDKAccessToken token null or not null.after you got the solution

Comment: please add some code so other people find your solution

Comment: I get the token in the handler `-(void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error {` and it is not `null`. @user1345